# При каких минимальных настройках в tsconfig.json работает автоматический импорт/экспорт типов .d.ts?

Tags: typescript

Много пишут о том, что теперь в TypeScript можно не использовать директивы с тройным слэшем и что теперь `.d.ts` рекурсиврно подключаются при компиляции. Мало пишут о том, при каких настройках это работает.

У меня это не работает при следующих настройках:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "strict": true,

    "lib": [
      // Нужно для Array.prototype.includes()
      "es7"
    ]
  }
}
```

Структура проекта:

```
.
+-- TypeScrptSource
|   +-- FileName.ts
|   +-- FileName.d.ts
+-- tsconfig.json
+-- webpack.config.js
```

Тип, определённый в **FileName.d.ts**, не виден в **FileName.ts**. Определён в виде

```
export type SomeType = {
  testProp: string
};
```

Убедительная просьба: не добавляйте в `tsconfig.json` ничего, что не имеет отношения к данному вопросу.

Comment: если переименуете файл, например в `typings.d.ts`, то все заработает, потому что у них [одинаковые наименования](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts#L2645), во-вторых не `export type`, а `declare type`

Comment: @overthesanity, благодарю Вас за ответ! Не буду проверять, пока не проясню один организационный момент. Я практикую полноценное ООП, а потому в идеале, если бы все типы были упакованы в классы, c которыми они  логически связаны. К сожалению, TypeScript этого не позволяет, потому следующее, что возможно - назвать файл с классом так же, как и класс, а типы поместить в одноимённый файл с расширением d.ts. Теперь оказалось, что и этого нельзя (typings.d.ts - не понятно, к какому классу относятся типы в этом файле). Что же можно ещё сделать для приближения к идеалу?

Comment: @БоковГлеб а зачем вы вообще разделяете эти два файла? Почему вы не можете написать всё что нужно в одном?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Поместить типы выше класса - мешаются. Ниже класса  - далеко прокручивать, чтобы посмотреть на них. Кроме того, хотя типы и связаны с классами, они используются за пределами класса (например, когда надо запросить через get-ер данные какого-либо типа, определённого внутри класса, нужно аннотировать тип переменной, к которой мы будем присваивать то, что вернёт get-ер). Придется разделять импорты на импорт по умолчанию и не по умолчанию.

Comment: @БоковГлеб вам в любом случае придется разделять импорты, если вы будете продолжать использовать одноименные модули, ведь это по сути один и тот же модуль (и это при условии что вы сумеете как-то обойти ограничение языка). Почему бы вам не придумать свою схему наименования? Например, `ClassName.ts` и `ClassName.types.ts`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, то есть не использовать двойное расширение `d.ts`? Если это - лучшее решение для полностью ООП-базированного приложения, то почему бы и нет. Правда, преимущество `d.ts` в том, что его ну нужно импортировать в явном виде...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расширение `.d.ts` предназначено для тайпингов к `.js` - модулям. Говорить, что их не нужно импортировать в явном виде - некорректно, поскольку вы всё равно должны импортировать `.js`-модуль, а `.d.ts`-модуль всегда идет к нему парой.

Модули же, написанные на TypeScript, в отдельных тайпингах не нуждаются, и таковые компилятором не поддерживаются. А потому одновременное наличие в проекте `FileName.ts` и `FileName.d.ts` является ошибкой.

Если вы хотите разделить основные и вспомогательные типы по разным файлам - вам нужна своя схема именования. Например, `FileName.ts` и `FileName.types.ts`. Да, второй файл придется импортировать вручную - но это всего лишь одна строчка кода.

Comment: Благодаря Вам полное понимание, к которому я стремлюсь, достигнуто. Благодраю Вас за ответ!